# Javascript Strigify Push and Shift given me error

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am  new to javascript, please help me with this code, where did I get it wrong?

```
function magix2(arrangment, figures) {
    arrangment.push(figures);
    return arrangment.shift();
}

var bum = [26,27,28,29,30,31,32];

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(arrangment));
console.log(magix2(bum, 33));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(arrangment));
```

Comment: please show a complete snippet.

Comment: And what error you are getting ?

Comment: `arrangment` is a local variable to `magix2` function, it's not accessible outside of that function. You need to retrieve `bum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function magix2(arrangment, figures) {
  arrangment.push(figures);
  return arrangment.shift();
}
```

`var bum = [26,27,28,29,30,31,32];`

`//console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(arrangment));`

`console.log(magix2(bum, 33));`

`//console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(arrangment));`

`arrangment` is the argument of function, you can't access that argument outside the function, that's I commented out these console lines.

Answer (score 0):

`arrangment` is an argument of `magix2` function you can not access it outside. Try accessing `bum` instead.

```js
function magix2(arrangment, figures) {
    arrangment.push(figures);
    return arrangment.shift();
}

var bum = [26,27,28,29,30,31,32];

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(bum));
console.log(magix2(bum, 33));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(bum));
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to perform your operation. Console Return 26, as it is first element, also 33 is added to list
[image: The correct way to perform your operation. Console Return 26, as it is first element, also 33 is added to list]